# Isekai manga with student council MC and girls on council who help elves. He has more than one hero symbol

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for the name of manga where the MC (main character) and his Student Council group are summoned in *isekai* fashion (total 4 people including him). Other than him, the others are all girls who are always making fun of him. He and one of the girls in the group (he is Vice President and the girl is President of the Student Council) help the resident elves who were kidnapped by monsters. Also, he has more than one hero symbol, while the other in his group just have one symbol.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You really need to add some more details; all you have is an all-girl student council.  In addition to details of the story, please add anything you can recall about where and when you read it, art style, cover art, etc.

Comment: It does need more details, but also probably more than an hour before it is closed for lacking them.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. If any further details come up (maybe because someone's answer makes you remember more details), you can [edit] your question to add them in.

Comment: It's a somewhat superficial match, but [*The Wrong Way to use Healing Magic](https://kissmanga.in/kissmanga/the-wrong-way-to-use-healing-magic-ggg/chapter-1/) features a main character who's transported to another world with the president and vice-president of the student council.

Answer (score 1):

This vaguely reminds me of *Isekai Yurutto Survival Seikatsu: Gakkou no Minna to Isekai no Mujintou ni Tenishitakedo Ore Dake Rakushou desu*, often translated as "Easy Survival Life in the Other World" or "Everyone in School Transferred to an Uninhabited Island in the Other World but It’s an Easy Victory".

[image: Cover of Isekai Yurutto Survival Seikatsu: Gakkou no Minna to Isekai no Mujintou ni Tenishitakedo Ore Dake Rakushou desu]

> Isekai Yurutto Survival Seikatsu: Gakkou no Minna to Isekai no Mujintou ni Tenishitakedo Ore Dake Rakushou desu summary: I’m Shinomiya Hokage, a 3rd-year high-school boy who dreams of a survival life. One day, everyone in my school transferred to a mysterious island in a parallel world. I woke up in an unknown cave and I started moving on my own. Then, I met up with some of my classmates. My knowledge and tools in survival shines through. I was a plain guy in school but I’m the leader in this world.

The girls are not "student council", but are "a high rank group in the class". The main character is teased and bullied with a nickname of "Ninja" based on his name of "[Hokage](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hokage)" with the girls being noted by him as being among those who threw erasers at him.

Found with a search for `isekai manga "survival otaku"` based on dim memories of seeing this come up before.

It apparently originated as [an online novel](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/easy-survival-life-in-the-other-world-everyone-in-school-transferred-to-an-uninhabited-island-in-the-other-world-but-its-an-easy-victory-for-me/).